# Script or Automate Cloning of Azure App and Database for Testing

Tags: azure-web-apps

I will immediately admit that I might be going the wrong way about this, but, I would like to be able to have this setup:

Have an `Azure App`, say myappstaging.azurewebsites.net, that we'll call Staging and a `database` that, when I need to, be automatically recreated from another `Azure App` and `database`, that we'll call Production.

It would be nice if it kept the same publish settings so that I wouldn't have to constantly tinker with my `Visual Studio` `Publish Settings`

Does such a thing exist or is possible? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Azure SQL, you can copy a database with either PowerShell script or T-SQL, as it is mentioned here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy

For the app of Azure App Service, you can have either two separate App Service or using different slots of one App Service. The connection string can be configured in the app service settings so you don't need to change your code for it.

But I think you still need two publishing profiles in Visual Studio.